# Update progress bar slower

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar

I am using [progress](https://pypi.org/project/progress/) to render progress bars for a long computational process.  The issue stems from the fact that I am using a `for` loop with lots of items that are each processed very quickly.  This causes the progress bar to update itself rapidly, causing the time remaining to change quickly between nearby seconds, such as flickering between 10 and 11 or 10 and 9.

I've tried adding `time.sleep(1)` but this slows down the computation as well.

My code looks as follows:

```py
fbar = Bar("Scanning:",max=maxindex,suffix='%(percent)d%% %(eta)s seconds remaining...')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        # setup computation
    else:
        # computation
    fbar.next()
fbar.finish()
```

I would like the progress bar to update slower, such that it doesn't look like the time remaining is flickering.

Comment: have you tried tqdm?

Comment: @Chris That works.  If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll award it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TQDM](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm), it's very robust and configurable and will solve your problem!